# Unity - The LineRender (visual) does not match the Positions of the LineRender

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

I'm trying to let an object follow a predicent path in Unity.

1. First I calculate the path in Circle.cs
2. Then I store the points in the LineRender component
3. I let an object follow the positions in Path.cs

The problem : The LineRender (visual) does not match the Positions of the LineRender. See : [Screenshot Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69pog.png)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Path : MonoBehaviour
{

    // The linerender path to follow
    public LineRenderer path;

    // The speed at which to follow the path
    public float speed = 5.0f;

    // The current position on the path
    private int currentPosition = 0;

  void Update()
    {
        // Get the current position and target position on the path
        Vector3 currentWaypoint = path.GetPosition(currentPosition);
        Vector3 targetWaypoint = path.GetPosition(currentPosition + 1);

        // Move towards the target waypoint
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetWaypoint, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        // If we have reached the target waypoint, move to the next one
        if (transform.position == targetWaypoint)
        {
            currentPosition++;

            // If we have reached the end of the path, start again from the beginning
            if (currentPosition >= path.positionCount)
            {
                currentPosition = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Circle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float radius = 3;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private int numPoints = 100;
    private Vector3[] positions;
    
    void Start()
    {
        positions = new Vector3[numPoints];
        float angleIncrement = (Mathf.PI / 2) / numPoints; // Quarter circle in radians

        for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
        {
            float angle = angleIncrement * i;
            float x = radius * Mathf.Cos(angle);
            float y = radius * Mathf.Sin(angle);
            positions[i] = new Vector3(x, 0, y);
        }
        this.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().positionCount = numPoints;
        this.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPositions(positions);
    }
}
```

I tried to adjust the scale of the LineRender.

Comment: I have identified the issue. The points were being rendered from the origin (x:0, y:0, z:0), but the LineRender object had a positional offset. I adjusted the position of the LineRender object to the origin and the line now matches the positions as expected.

Comment: You could add a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) showing how you fixed the problem. That way others can learn from what you figured out.

Answer (score 0):

By default the positions of a LineRenderer component are based on world-spaced coordinates.

Thus, you have two options for a fix here:

1. Set the `useWorldSpace` attribute on the LineRenderer to `false` (either in code or in the inspector)
2. Add the offset to the points, before you add them to the LineRenderer